# Connection to Hive/BigData through Knowage in Fiware ecosystems

Tags: docker, hive, bigdata, fiware, fiware-knowage

I'm new to Knowage and Fiware ecosystem, I'm building a dataflow to store context data in Orion and to persist these data to HDFS through Cygnus. Now,  I'm experimenting to connect Knowage to my Spark/Hadoop env to visualize and analyze these data, but I'm having a lot of difficulty configuring the correct jars for the Hive2 JDBC connector. I'm using the knowage:8.0 docker image, retrieved from docker hub, and I noticed that in $(TOMCAT_HOME)/webapps/knowage/WEB-INF/lib there aren't the connectors to Hive/Hive2/Spark, so I supposed to manually put them there, but It's being really struggle...
My question, is it possible in any way to connect Knowage Community Edition to any BigData source? I read this on documentation, in the section about Big Data and NoSQL (https://knowage-suite.readthedocs.io/en/master/administrator-guide/configure-data-sources.html):

*"Please note that these connections are available for products KnowageBD and KnowagePM only."*

I tried with different versions of hive-jdbc, but always get the same exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.isValid(HiveConnection.java:1018)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:916)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:282)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:362)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2340)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2323)
    ... 50 more
```

Here the popup message from Knowage UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUIDB.png

Comment: Unless you can create a [reproducible snippet of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then Stack Overflow as a Q+A site is probably not the right forum to open this issue. I would suggest you try and engage the Knowage team directly by raising an issue on their [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/KnowageLabs/Knowage-Server)

Comment: Thanks @JasonFox . There isn't a snippet of code, I created a new Data Source directly from the Knowage UI. My question is if KnowageCE is able to connect to Big Data/NoSQL sources..despite what it's said in the official documentation.